# Unknown system function: format-date in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am oxygen editor to transform data XML into CSV format. To transform, I am using XSLT. I am using `format-date` function to convert date value in desired format.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(wd:Evaluate_Employee_Effective_Date,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')" />
```

Also, how do I know that which version of XSLT I am using?

Comment: Are you using the XSLT Debugger? If so, you should see the processor in the upper left hand corner (either Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5 or Saxon 9 (HE/PE/EE)). Also make sure you have the version attribute on `xsl:stylesheet` set to 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I am using XSLT Debugger in OXygen editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error, it looks like you are using unsupported version of validation engine. Please choose `Saxon-HE/PE/EE 9.5.1.7` instead of `Saxon6.5.5`
If you are using eclipse or Oxygen editor, you can find this settings under `preferences > XML > XSLT-FO-XQuery`.

In Oxygen editor, you can choose engine from drop-down available in the left corner of control bar (below the menu bar).

Let me know if didn't work.

Comment: What you are talking about are not "validation engines", they are XSLT processors. Please clarify that.